# Unable to set and get value of hidden element in form

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to set and get the value of a hidden form element. My js code is as follows

```
var resp= document.forms["registration"]["userid_response"];
resp.value="true";

var check_userid_response = document.registration.userid_response.value;
console.log(check_userid_response);
```

My html code is as follows

```
<form name="registration" id="registration" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="userid_response" id="userid_response" value="">
</form>
```

The javascript console shows "an empty string".

Please help me. My project is stuck due to this.

Comment: Something else is going on - works fine here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/pvpKXo

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/uqr0fju1/

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/TNAC6/116/

Comment: Check your browser `console`  you might fine an error message displayed.